# Random numbers within a range excluding zero

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to create a Random number generator using, `java.util.Random`. I need to generate numbers between -5 and +5 excluding zero. This is for bouncingbox app for one of my labs. The random number is the direction of the velocity of the box.

```
Random v = new Random();
       int deltaX = -5 + v.nextInt(10)  ;
       for(; deltaX>0 && deltaX<0;){

           System.out.println(deltaX);
       }
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't exclude zero. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have got plenty of input, you should accept an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
int deltaX = -5 + v.nextInt(10);
if (deltaX >= 0) deltaX++;
```

Comment: This is a nice algorithm.  The answer that I had prepared was identical to Pshemo's, however this one is simpler and more performant.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way:

```
int[] outcomeSet = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int deltaX = outcomeSet[v.nextInt(10)];
```

If the `outcomeSet` is made static this should be the most computationally efficient.

Comment: +1 for a clean solution, no branching and one liner(set is declared once). However, I usually don't use extra memory when you can do it in another way.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Thanks for the upvote. It seems there's always some trade-off between computation and memory. I don't think 40 bytes is a show-stopper, though, even way back in the '70's when I could only get a 16k allocation on the mainframe.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution without regeneration the random each time is to use the following algorithm:

```
public int getRandomWithExclusion(Random rnd, int start, int end, int... exclude) {
    int random = start + rnd.nextInt(end - start + 1 - exclude.length);
    for (int ex : exclude) {
        if (random < ex) {
            break;
        }
        random++;
    }
    return random;
}
```

The following can be either called with an array reference:

```
int[] ex = { 2, 5, 6 };
val = getRandomWithExclusion(rnd, 1, 10, ex)
```

or by directly inserting the numbers into the call:

```
val = getRandomWithExclusion(rnd, 1, 10, 2, 5, 6)
```

**It generates a random number (int) between start and end (both inclusive) and does not give you any number which is contained in the array exclude. All other numbers occur with equal probability. Note, that the following constrains must hold: exclude is sorted ascendingly and all numbers are within the range provided and all of them are mutually different.**

Answer (score 2):

I like other answers which random in range [-5,4] and if value is 0 or grater they add 1 making real range `[-5; -1] [1; 5]`.

But here is some easier approach, although not shorter.

```
Random v = new Random();

boolean makeNegative = v.nextBoolean();
int value = v.nextInt(5) + 1; // range [1; 5]

if (makeNegative)
    value = -value;
```

It is less effective because it requires two random values (boolean and int) but code is easier to read.

Comment: I have an answer too, but yours is at least as good as mine. You're generating 2 values for one output, I may get the answer from 1st time, maybe 2nd time, but it can be worse too. It's working nice for small intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:-

```
int deltaX = -5 + v.nextInt(10); 
if (deltax >= 0) deltax++;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do {
  deltaX = -5 + v.nextInt(11);
} while (deltaX == 0)
```

The easiest way, still random(no +1).

Comment: You wind up looping unnecessarily, and you will never get +5 either.

Comment: Oh come on, it's not unnecessarily, you need a random number, not 1 every time you get a 0. Also, for +5, it's a matter of parameters, not bad thinking.

Comment: Updated, now I get +5 too.

Comment: The problem with a loop is you are not guaranteed to return a value. if check plus increment is a guaranteed constant time. Here, in theory, you might never return.

Comment: Theory is good, but the theory also say that this is random and I will not get enough zeros to hang the flow of the application. I can bet that the loop won't run for more than 10 times. I have 1/11 chances to get a 0 for first time, 1/121 to get 2 zeros. My chances are dropping rapidly. I agree that there might be a problem for small deltas, like +/- 1, +/- 2, but +/- 5 is already enough to get a decent result.

Comment: @Charlie Theory also tells us that the expected number of iterations of the loop is 12/11 and that the chance of needing more than 10 iterations is on the order of one in a hundred billion.

Comment: This full stop wastes time, if it was the only way fair enough, but you can get an answer without a loop at all

Comment: @RichardTingle I personally hate branching and extra space, I try to avoid it in my code every time I can. What's your excuse?

Comment: I prefer clarity and efficiency

Comment: For clarity I'd have one rand to decide sign and one for 1-5. For efficiency I'd have one of the if>0 add one answers

Comment: That's not efficient enough if you ask me.

Comment: @RichardTingle I think the direct table lookup is the most efficient.

Comment: I agree the two randoms isnt efficient, its maximum clarity. Is the direct table lookup prefilled values?

Comment: I was also thinking about lookup table, it's a decent solution, but for other similar problems it won't work if the set of values is not finite.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Agreed. It's also not so hot for a large set of unequal probabilities, in which case I'd recommend an alias table. However, for this particular case it'd be pretty hard to beat - no additional arithmetic required other than the (internal) array offset calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
Random random = new Random();
int random = random.nextInt(5) + 1;
int result = random.nextBoolean() ? random : -random;
```

Yes its less effective because it requires two random values. The resulting intervals are [-5 - 0) and [1 - 5]